# Map complex type to anonymous object

Tags: automapper, anonymous-types

- Let's have well known complex type (CT, e.g. `Dto` from the example).
- Let's have set of type converters (functions) transforming value of one type to another (e.g. `int SubDto2ToInt(SubDto2 sub)`, `string GuidToString(Guid gd)`).

**Is there any method, how to configure Automapper and tell him:**

***"Map CT using these provided Type Converters and create object of anonymous type."*?**

This would effectively:

- go over all CT's properties (recursively)
- check the list of converters

  - if any present for given property type, convert and add to the result
  - otherwise proceed the default way (put it "as is" to the result)

I have had partial success when I pre-created the anonymous type, but that does not make much sense, because I can then create "normal" target type and define classic mapping. So the point is to let the Automapper create the target type on his own. The target member types would then be driven by either the source type or the conversion result type (if registered).

Example:

```
class SubDto1 { int M1; int M2; }  // Pretend they are get/set properties
class SubDto2 { int N1; int N2; }  // dtto
class Dto { SubDto1 Sub1; SubDto2 Sub2; Guid Id; } // dtto

var source = new Dto { Sub1 = new SubDto1 {M1 = 1, M2 = 2}, Sub2 = new SubDto2 {N1 = 10, N2 = 20}, Id = Guid.NewGuid()};
var expectedTargetEquivalentTo = new
{
    Sub1 = new {M1 = 1, M1 = 2},                 // No conversion registered here, "as is"
    Sub2 = 30,                                   // Fancy SubDto2 -> int conversion registered here
    Id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Guid -> string conversion registered here
}
```

Comment: Why not have a DTO instead of the anonymous type?

Comment: Just don't want to define it (lot of additional types to maintain/sync with the originals).

Comment: I don't see it. It would just compose other types, nothing to sync/maintain. By using an anonymous type, you're making things difficult for yourself.